# Using React hooks to set state and local storage and React is saying I am making too many calls

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, local-storage

I have a small React component that simply uses a Rich Text Editor(TinyMCE) to edit values in a text field displayed on a web app.

I've found that if I type too fast or too much, I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate.

But I'm not using either `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`

So I am not sure why React is telling me that.

I've tried fixing, but nothing I do helps.

I'd appreciate any insight! :)

Here is my React component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = (props) => {
    const [engineText, setEngineTextState] = useState(props.engineText || "Describe your engine...");
    const [engineId, setEngineIdState] = useState(props.engineId);
    var edValue = '';

    // first check local storage to see if they already have typed something...use engineId as the unique key
    if (localStorage.getItem(engineId)) {
        edValue = localStorage.getItem(engineId);
    } else {
        edValue = engineText;
    }

    const [engineState, setEngineState] = useState(edValue);

    // set the local storage in case user navigates away and then comes back we don't lose what they wrote
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(engineId, engineState)
    }, [engineState]);

    // update database
    const updateEngineText = (content) => {
        const request = axios.put(`/api/EngineManagementConsole/${engineId}/engineText`, JSON.stringify(content), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        setEngineState(content);
    }
    return (
        <Editor
            initialValue={edValue}
            init={{
                height: 500,
                menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
                plugins: [
                    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                ]
            }}
            value={engineState}
            onEditorChange={updateEngineText}
        />
    )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component will check `localStorage` and set the value of `edValue` on every single render.  This is passed as the `initialValue` prop to `Editor` so it will cause the `Editor` component to re-render.

Since this is just an initial value, you probably meant to only evaluate it once.  We can use `useMemo` for that.

Your `edValue` is derived from both `engineId` and `engineText` so those should be the dependencies of the `useMemo`.  It will be re-evaluated if either of those variables changes.

It seems silly to duplicate the props `engineId` and `engineText` as a state when it seems like you are not updating their state anywhere.  Just use the props directly.

```
const App = ({engineId, engineText = "Describe your engine..."}) => {

    const edValue = useMemo( () => {
         // function to create the value
         return localStorage.getItem(engineId) || engineText;
         // dependencies array
         }, [engineId, engineText]
    );

    const [engineState, setEngineState] = useState(edValue);
...
```

Note: I'm not sure if is the *only* issue, there might be other problems causing the error.

Comment: Thank you! Would I need to get rid of the `useEffect()` that I use? Also, I also assume that I don't need this line anymore: `var edValue = '';`  I will test this out! Thanks!

Comment: Hi again, so I tested this out and it's not erroring me out anymore.  It's working much better, but I've noticed that when I edit the text in the component, leave the page, then come back, the text still says `"Describe your engine..."`. So for some reason, it's not getting the new text from storage. Now if I refresh the page, it does get the new text.  So I'm wondering if I need to put the `useEffect()` statement back in...because that's where I had `localStorage.setItem` ?  thank you!

Comment: Still no luck :( I ended up not re-adding the `useEffect()` statement back in.  But I did move the `localStorage.setItem(engineId, engineState)`  to the `updateEngineText()` function thinking this would work.  However, it is saving the correct/updated text to the database and the local storage.  But for some reason, when I navigate away, then back again, it shows "Describe your engine..." instead of what is stored in localStorage until I refresh the page manually.